# Animate the size of halo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to access the size of a gameobjects Halo component in a c# script. 
I've tried using  but it says that the namespace cannot be found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I am looking for a similar feature. At the very least you can turn it on and off using this code...

```
(gameObjectname.GetComponent("Halo") as Behaviour).enabled = true (or false)
```

Comment: @noufalcep Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow, but why did my comment get edited? The content is the same with the edit, you just changed ":" to "..." and "I'm" to "I am." Does this automatically down vote my post?